# Firing javascript with new string parameters without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't know how to phrase the title correctly to explain what I need help with, so here's my story..

The code below writes an iframe with a video in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sv.liveclicker.net/service/getEmbed?client_id=1915&amp;widget_id=1372752183&amp;player_custom_id=2264&amp;height=450&amp;width=800&amp;autoplay=false"></script>
```

I can't directly make changes to the script above so how can I remove that script (and the generated iframe), then call that same script again with modified parameters (height and width) so that writes out a new iframe/video with my new dimensions - and without page refresh (well, the refresh would just null out any changes and revert back to the old script again).

By the way, the client_id, widget_id and player_custom_id needs to stay the same as it was originally on the page.

If this can be done in jQuery, that would be awesome (just started learning).

Thanks for your help everyone.

Additional Info: In chrome when I click on that script src it gives me this:

```
if (!window.liveclicker) window.liveclicker = {};
if (!window.liveclicker || !liveclicker.receiveMessage) {
    var lcs = document.createElement('script');
    lcs.src = "http://sv.liveclicker.net/service/scripts/html5_js_c.js";
    lcs.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(lcs);
}

document.write('<iframe id="video_1372752183" name="video_1372752183" src="" width="800" height="450" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0;" webkitAllowFullScreen mozAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>');
liveclicker.post_to_name = function (path, params, name) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    form.setAttribute("target", name);
    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
};
liveclicker.post_to_name("//player.liveclicker.com/video-player/index.php\?widget_id=1372752183&accountid=1915&urlaccount=http://www.dhccare.com&accountCDN=http://ecdn.liveclicker.net/0079A8/cdn/&setrefererURL=http%3A%2F%2Fdhcstaging.liveclicker.com%2F&navfile=TODO&iframeDiv=video_1372752183&channel=0&player_custom_id=2264", {
    'shopapp_gview_buynow_avail': 0,
    'knobsEnabled': 'false',
    'shopapp_dview_buynow_avail': 0,
    'shareAvailable': 'false',
    'pseudo_streaming': 'true',
    'snapshotFeaturev2': 0,
    'buyAvailable': 'false',
    'navBuyNow': 'false',
    'aspectRatio': '16:9',
    'autostart': 'false',
    'ratingAvailablev2': 'false',
    'mosaic_skin': 'true',
    'sizing': 'crop',
    'channel': 2
}, "video_1372752183");
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Most likely you will need to inspect the HTML code that is generated by this script. Once you know what the DOM looks like, then you can leverage JQuery to do all you need: get attribute values, remove elements, create new elements, set the CSS style of elements, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to wrap your script tag in a div (id = "myDiv") and then load new videos/delete previous video using innerHTML as follows?

```
//Video1
<div id="myDiv">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sv.liveclicker.net/service/getEmbed?
client_id=1915&amp;widget_id=1372752183&amp;player_custom_id=2264&amp;height=450&amp;width=800&amp;autoplay=false"></script>
</div>
```

then call function onclick of a button or icon to load new video:

```
//New script here...not sure what your script would be so I just put previous one..you can add height and width as parameters onclick...num1 and num2 would be what you need them to be

<button type="button" onclick="changeVideo(num1, num2)">Click</button>

function changeVideo(height, width) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript"     
src="http://sv.liveclicker.net/service/getEmbed?client_id=&amp;widget_id=1372752183&amp;player_custom_id=2264&amp;height=' + height + '&amp;width=' + width + '&amp;autoplay=false"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's actually wrapped in a div. I tried your idea, but now I get this in chrome: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.